# authentication between phonegap and php

Tags: php, cordova, forms-authentication

i need a system of authentication between phonegap and php. I make a request by ajax sending the user and pass. Php make the query mysql with these data if is correct it is return the PHPSESSID and save with javascript in LocalStorage. when this user make actions as comments, upload photos.. check if exist PHPSESSID in LocalStore and check this PHPSESSID in php.

Is correct make this?

Comment: I need help to share PhoneGap PHP Sessions. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

It's better if you use RESTful principle which means the server is stateless. Try to dig up on how to make web services using rest. There should be tons of examples where you can try on.

Comment: There are really tons of website. Just search up "how to make restful api web service" on google. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

OAuth springs to mind. Store the token in localStorage rather than storing the session ID. That way, you can quickly and easily recall it.

You can also tweak your OAuth provider to auto-refresh tokens that are used, so tokens never really expire.

Comment: what token?? i don't save any token.